# Rails Bootstrap modal pass in value without javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with a Bootstrap modal.

Here is part of the code that launches the modal:

```
  <a type="button" class="btn" href="#labor_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-woid= <%= workorder.id %>><i class="icon-time"></i></a>
```

Here's part of the code for the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="labor_modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
  <h3>Add Labor</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= simple_form_for(Event.new, validate: true, remote: true, html: {"data-type" => :json}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :workorder_id, :value => data-woid.val() %>
```

I want to get the work order.id passed to the modal so it can be saved in the new record.

This code isn't working:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :workorder_id, :value => data-woid.val()
```

Any help would be appreciated !!

PS - I was hoping I could do this without jquery - but, if I need it so be it.

Comment: You have to use a javascript, and this solution, to me, has the cleanest solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/24962060/1612469

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= %>` is an ERb (embedded Ruby) tag. Inside should be Ruby code.

```
data-woid.val()
```

is not valid Ruby in the context which you use it.

ERb is processed before rendering HTML. At the time ERb is processed, Ruby is not aware of the DOM or rendered HTML elements or their attributes. There is no way to read HTML data attributes in Ruby via ERb. You must access them after the page is rendered and the DOM is built. Use JavaScript/jQuery for this.

I'm guessing that `work_order.id` will be used to set an association. Exposing this to the user is insecure; it is possible to change the value to anything before submitting. Associations should be set in the controller, specifically the `create` action before you call `save`.

Comment: It's going to be in a hidden input field

Comment: OK - I'll try using jquery

Comment: Hidden inputs are hidden from view only. They are still present in the DOM and can be altered with a little bit of JavaScript. Or one could save the page source, alter it, open in another window, then post the form. Or post an altered request via curl. Hidden fields are not secure.

Answer (score 0):

Well the question said **without javascript**. My answer might not work in every scenario or answer the question perfectly, plus it is will not scale, but it uses no javascript!

So what I would do is **create as many modals as I need** according to the parameter. I would do that by assigning them different ids. This can be done dynamically on rails.

Then each link would open (reveal) its matching modal, and it would **seem like a parameter was sent**, because each modal would have the necessary information, set at render time.