# How to pass a parameter from a link element to a modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, parameter-passing

I have a table. In a cell of the table there is a link like this: 
    `<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="xyz" href="#remoteModal" data-target="#remoteModal">SOME_TEXT</a>`.

When I click on this link should open a modal. Here's an example:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="remoteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="remoteModal" aria-hidden="true">
  Some HTML/PHP Code
</div>
```

The modal must perform some operations that depend on the value of "data-id" attribute. To be precise, in the javascript code I need to read this value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ( ) {
    $('#remoteModal').on('show.bs.modal', function( event ) {
        console.log( /* How do I read the value of data-id? */ );
    });
});
```

I do not know how to read the value of this attribute in the javascript code of the modal.

Many thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [the `.relatedTarget` property](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target) mentioned in the [Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) Event docs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#remoteModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        console.log($(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is this code not working then http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7147/ Strange because for the show event it works in my code on dev server, but not in jsfiddle... The hide is not working on both (undefined).

Comment: @Dante Because you're using ancient Bootstrap v2.1.0's JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Global Variable
value = '';

$('[href = #remoteModal]').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        value = $(this).data("id");
        $('#remoteModal').show();
});
```

And I think you can access to `value` variable everywhere in this page

Comment: I know and I do not like this solution. I would like to know if I can pass an argument to modal and read it within the "show.bs.modal" event.

Comment: And do you know you can access your id by typing `alert(value)` in your `show.bs.modal` . Sorry I don't know what you want but I think it depends on how you right your code for showing modal and so on...

Comment: The previous solution could be accepted, but when I close the modal, for example with the "ESC" key, the modal window is closed but the background is still dark. Also, I have to use to open the modal: $('#remoteModal').modal('show');. And not $('#remoteModal').show();

Answer (score 0):

```
var data-id = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

So here in **data-id** you wll get your "XYZ"

Comment: There are many rows in the table. Each row contains a link with a different ID. I can not use this solution

Comment: Different ID means attribute or value?

Comment: The value of the attribute.