# Bootstrap - Modal - relatedTarget after show/hide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

This is related to [How to pass a parameter from a link element to a modal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951453/how-to-pass-a-parameter-from-a-link-element-to-a-modal-window/24962060#24962060)

According to the answer the following jsFiddle should work => http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7152/

```
 $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
  alert($(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-id'));
 });

$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  alert($(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-id'));
});
```

But I get undefined alerted...
Strange thing => this code is copied from my development and there it works on the open event. But not when closing.

Does anyone see a difference? Or can get this to work based on the jsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @cvrebert - Chris Rebert.

I was using the wrong version of Bootstrap in my fiddle.
+ The hide event doesn't have a relatedTarget.

Thanks!