# Twitter BootStrap - Passing multiple data to one modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to know if it is possible to pass and retrieve multiple data values to a twitter bootstrap model?

So let's say that I have first and last name values retrieved from a database in a table (each have associated ids) etc.

Would I call the model as such:

**HTML**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteConfirm" data-id="{fist_name=fname,last_name=lname}" class="confirmDelete">
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".confirmDelete", function () {
    var first_name= $(this).data('first_name');
    var last_name= $(this).data('last_name');
    $(".modal-body #currDeleteId").val( userDeleteId );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would pass them as separate data attributes, like so:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteConfirm" data-first_name="fname" data-last_name="lname" class="confirmDelete">
```

And your JQuery would not have to change:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".confirmDelete", function () {
    var first_name= $(this).data('first_name');
    var last_name= $(this).data('last_name');
    $(".modal-body #currDeleteId").val( userDeleteId );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you'd access the values doing this, since you're using **data-id** in your html.

```
var first_name = $(this).data('id').first_name;
var last_name = $(this).data('id').last_name;
```

http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2

Comment: My issue lies with passing the data to the jquery function. When I do a console.log with your method i get undefined

Comment: You need to use `relatedTarget` instead of `this`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24962060/3342739